# get the text of a selectable element inside a ordered list jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following ordered list:

```
<ol class="list">
    <li id="1">one</li>
    <li id="2">two</li>
    <li id="3">three</li>
 </ol>
```

And I just want to get the text of the selectable li. I mean, when I click in one of the elements I want to get the text of this element. I tryed like this:

```
$(function() {
        $( ".list" ).selectable({
          stop: function() {
            $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
                 alert($(".list li").text());
            });
          }
        });
    });
```

But with this I just get the text of all `<li>` elements of the list and not the text of one selectable `<li>`
Is there a solution for this?

Comment: `$(this).text()` instead of `$('.list li').text()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/v9dhtL98/2/).

**JS**

```
$(function() {
        $( ".list" ).selectable({
          stop: function() {
            $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
                 console.log($(this).text());
            });
          }
        });
    });
```

**NOTE**: Use `$(this)` instead of `$(".list li")`.

Comment: Thx again! $(this) of course is more logical to use :)